# Definition about moduli space of Riemann Surfaces of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points, $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$

Tags: riemann-surfaces, moduli-space

In the definition of the moduli space of Riemann Surfaces of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points, $\mathcal{M}_{g,n}$, it is asked that $g$ and $n$ satisfy the condition $2-2g-n<0$. I've seen that this means that the Compact Riemann Surface of genus $g$ with $n$ marked points, $\Sigma_{g,n}$, has negative Euler Characteristic.
My questions are:

1. What does it mean that a Surface has a negative Euler characteristic?
2. Why do we need that condition?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What you have seen is not quite right. The correct claim is that if you remove $n$ points from a genus zero surface, then the stated inequality means that the punctured surface has negative Euler characteristic. The definition of Euler characteristic you can find in any algebraic topology book: it is the alternating sum of Betti numbers.